# Split a Java String

Tags: java, regex, parsing, context-free-grammar

I'm having a little trouble with Java regexes. I have a string like this

```
a + 4 * log(3/abs(1 – x)) + sen(-b/4 + PI)
```

and i need to split this in the following tokens:

```
{"a", "+", "4", "*", "log", "(3/abs(1 - x))", "+", "sen", "(-b/4 + PI)"}
```

Any idea?

I tried this PHP regex, but for some reason it won't work on Java

```
[a-z]+(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))|[a-z]+|\d+|\/|\-|\*|\+
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: What i must use instead?

Comment: How can we possibly show you what's wrong with your approach and how to fix it if you don't show us what your approach is? Please show us what you have tried and then we can help.

Comment: Maybe Guava's string utilities? https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

Comment: I would recommend Googling `parse java numeric expression` to check your options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Match All vs Splitting**

Matching and splitting are two sides of the same coin. This is quite tricky because Java does not support recursion and we have some nested parentheses. But this should do the trick:

**Java**

```
\(.*?\)(?![^(]*\))|[^\s(]+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/11).

To iterate over all the matches:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)(?![^(]*\\))|[^\\s(]+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // the match: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

**Explanation**

- `\(.*?\)(?![^(]*\))` matches an opening parenthesis and everything up to a closing parenthesis that is not followed by an opening par and more closing pars. This works for the `(simple(nesting))` in your expression, but would not work for `(this(kind)of(nesting))` (see PHP solution)
- `|` OR...
- `[^\s(]+` any chars that are not spaces or an opening par

**PHP Option with Recursion**

In PHP, we can use recursion to match the nested constructs more precisely (this will overcome the Java problem with `(this(kind)of(nesting))`:

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|[^\s(]+
```

Comment: FYI, added Java code. Also, in addition to Java option, added PHP option for matching of more complex nested parentheses. Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Done. :) I wasn't able to upvote before because i don't had 15 points of reputation

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small java program to split instead of using regular expression spli, see if this can help

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(splitExp("a + 4 * log(3/abs(1 – x)) + sen(-b/4 + PI)"));
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> splitExp(String exp) {

        StringBuilder chString = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> arrL = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < exp.length() ; i++ ) {

            char ch = exp.charAt(i);

            if(ch == ' ')
                continue;

            if(( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')) {
                chString = chString.append(String.valueOf(ch));
            }
            else {
                if (chString.length() > 0) {
                    arrL.add(chString.toString());
                    chString = new StringBuilder();
                }
                arrL.add(String.valueOf(ch));
            }
        }
        return arrL;
    }
}
```